# Xamarin Signed Release apk will install but not run

Tags: android, visual-studio-2013, xamarin, monogame

I've been developing an app for a while and now I want to hand it out to friends for testing. The app works perfectly when debugging to my device but when I build and sign the apk and move it to my device I can install it without any errors but it will not run (I don't even get any error messages). Sometimes the screen goes black as if the app is about to start but then it just reverts back to the previous screen (One time the Monogame splash screen appeared before it reverted to the previous screen).

Here is what I have done so far and any specific details:

I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2014 with Xamarin.Android 4.20.

I'm creating my app using MonoGame.

I have cleaned and built my app in Release mode.

These are my packaging options:[image]

These are my linker options:[image]
(I believe choosing "None" only means my apk will be larger).

I created a keystore using Java's keytool.

I created and signed the apk using Xamarin's Visual Studio "Publish" command.

After all of this the apk will still not run.

Comment: Have you tried to `zipalign` your signed .apk file ? I had similar issue once and running this command helped me

Comment: The Publish command runs zipalign on the signed package itself, and the VS output window states that it runs successfully. Still, when I'm next at my computer I'll attempt to align it myself

Comment: Still the same results as before, although I think I'm on to the real issue. It could be an exception which is only thrown when the app starts in Release mode. I'll post an answer in a while if this is the case.

Comment: Ok, great, it will be interesting to find out what's causing it. Also worth mentioning some permissions are required to be set for release mode but not in debug ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out this was nothing to do with the signing or building of the release mode apk, it was actually down to an exception which was only being thrown when the app was built in release mode (I have no idea why this was the case).

The thing that was throwing the exception was the [DotNetZip library](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/), I'd post an issue on it's page but it looks like the project is dead anyway (Also, they don't explicitly support Xamarin Android).

My solution was to use [ZipStorer](http://zipstorer.codeplex.com/) alongside Mono's .Net compression implementation. Everything works nicely now.